# Eclipse PHP Neon.2 with Subversive produces project connection error after committing a PHP-configured project

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, subversive

In testing Neon and the new Subversive version's interaction with existing workspace projects prior to migrating my team's IDE installations, I've come upon a curious issue that did not take place using Mars.1 with Subversive 3.0.2 and Native JavaHL 1.8.1.

I've found that when a project has been "configured as a PHP project", any non-empty ('may apply to empty ones as well) commit results in one or more of a startling-looking error, one that [causes the project to disconnect from source control.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7wT6.png)
(The commit meanwhile, goes through to the server just fine.)

That can be easily remedied via the team=>share project command, but I'm interested in stopping the problem from taking place.
The error turns up in the log as a failure of "Get Resource List" to connect to the project, followed by a cascade of other SVN-related tasks failing for the same reason, until the logger gives up out of enui and says "... 9 more".

Killing the build commands `org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder` and `org.eclipse.dltk.core.scriptbuilder`, as well as the `org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature` nature in the .project file to make it act like a fresh unadulterated project prevents the issue, but naturally that's not an acceptable solution either, since that disables the nice DLTK toys, like occurance highlighting.

I actually made a [post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1084461/) on the eclipse forums about the issue, and learned much of the above while engaging in continued investigation, including a lot of failures to replicate until hitting on the .project settings.

Admittedly I didn't find anything recent that was really like this on their bugzilla, so I may just have to submit a bug report on this, but are there any *known* issues involving negative interaction between Subversive and one of those modules?  And/or any known work-arounds that aren't as dumb as "tell them to ignore the errors and manually re-connect" or "don't configure as PHP"?

To be complete about environment, I'm using Eclipse PHP Neon.2 with Subversive 4.0.2 using Native JavaHL 1.8.15, all on good ol' 64b win 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply switching to the SVNKit connector has sufficed, it turns out.

No telling if there were or not known issues, even after my combing through their bugzilla, but, experimentation resulted in several issue-free commits while configured as PHP using the SVNKit connector instead (SVNKit 1.8.14), so the issue could well be in JavaHL, either 1.8.15 specifically or any range of versions from 1.8.15 back to 1.8.2 at the oldest.